# Knockout mapping: getJSON call inside mapping's create

Tags: knockout.js, getjson, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got a JSON with an element containing a list of URLs.

(eg. `{'nome':'MyName', 'impila_tipo_lista': ['http://','http://',],}`)

I want to call each of those urls via $.getJSON to populate (and replace) this list with the list of corresponding items (json: {'nome':'MyOtherName',}.

```
var TipiDiFrammentiModel = function(url) {
    var self = this;

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        viewModel.impila_tipo_lista.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(json));

        self.isEditable = ko.observable(false);
        self.setIsEditable = function() { self.isEditable(true) };
    });

}

// MAPPATURA
var mapping = {
    // ...
    impila_tipo_lista: {
        create: function(options) {
            return new TipiDiFrammentiModel(options.data)
        },
    },
};

// ISTANZA
var viewModel = {
}
//...

// RUNTIME
$.getJSON('/rest/pila/{{ pila.slug }}', function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, viewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

So far, that's my ugly workaround.

```
ko.toJSON($data,null,4):

{
    "nome": "MyName",
    ...
    "impila_tipo_lista": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ],
    "__ko_mapping__": {
        "impila_lista": {},
        "impila_tipo_lista": {},
        "ignore": [],
        "include": [
            "_destroy"
        ],
        "copy": [],
        "observe": [],
        "mappedProperties": {
            "url": true,
            "nome": true,
            "slug": true,
            "impila_tipo_normale": true,
            "prosegui": true,
            "impila_lista": true,
            "impila_tipo_lista": true
        },
        "copiedProperties": {}
    }
}
```

BTW i cannot replace original urls with new item retrived. Indeed, i solved this puzzle some time ago, with getJSON and direct substitution of items to url in ko.mapping create... oh, my!

**EDIT**: Sort of. Still ugly, but working:

```
$.getJSON('/rest/pila/{{ pila.slug }}', function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, viewModel);

    $.each(viewModel.impila_tipo_lista(), function(i, val) {            
        $.getJSON(val, function(json) { 
            viewModel.impila_tipo_lista.splice(i, 1, ko.mapping.fromJS(json));
        });
    });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

**EDIT 2: That's works.** 
Notice, however, commented out code: if, to get rid of the finally `$.each part`, I enable `impila_tipo_lista` customization on create, **exactly the same way** `impila_lista` does, mapping miserably fails **for both** `impila_lista` *and* `impila_tipo_lista`...

```
// MODELLI
var FrammentiModel = function(url) {
    var self = this;

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        self.isEditable = ko.observable(false);
        self.setIsEditable = function() { self.isEditable(true) };

        self.advancedEdit = ko.observable(false);
        self.toggleAdvancedEdit = function() { self.advancedEdit(!self.advancedEdit()) };

        self.needCreate = ko.observable(false);

        ko.mapping.fromJS(json, mapping.impila_lista, self);
    });
}

var TipiDiFrammentiModel = function(url) {
    var self = this;

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

        ko.mapping.fromJS(json, mapping.impila_tipo_lista, self);
    });
}

// MAPPATURA
var mapping = {
    impila_lista: {
        create: function(options) {
            return new FrammentiModel(options.data)
        },
    },
    impila_tipo_lista: {
        //create: function(options) {
        //    return new TipiDiFrammentiModel(options.data)
        //},
    },
};

$.getJSON('/rest/pila/{{ pila.slug }}', function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, viewModel);

    $.each(viewModel.impila_tipo_lista(), function(i, val) {            
        $.getJSON(val, function(json) { 
            viewModel.impila_tipo_lista.splice(i, 1, ko.mapping.fromJS(json));
        });
    });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: I tried `$.getJSON(url, function(json) { ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {}, self) })` as well...

Comment: worst than ever: binding processor doesn't like at all modified observable arrays (`impila_lista` _and_ `impila_tipo_lista`) and root level properties neither...